# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 Com WebService JAX-RS e Android Retrofit

Tags: java, android, web-service, retrofit, jax-rs

Estou estudando WebService e consumo no Android com Retrofit2.

Já fiz testes com APIs públicas como ViaCEP e FIPE e consigo usar o retrofit tranquilamente, bem fácil mas quando montei meu próprio webservice usando JAX-RS com Jersey tenho problemas. Vou postar os detalhes para vocês me ajudarem se puderem.

A Mensagem de erro é:

> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2

---

Resultado ao chamar o recurso no WebService - Arquivo JSON:

URL: http://MEUSERVER:8080/locadorafilmes/filmes

```js
{
  "filmes": {
    "filme": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "titulo": "E o vento levou",
        "ano": "1961-01-12T00:00:00-03:00",
        "idioma": "Português",
        "atorPrincipal": "ValdikSoriano",
        "locado": false,
        "valorDiaria": 2.65
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "titulo": "Titanic",
        "ano": "1998-01-12T00:00:00-02:00",
        "idioma": "Português",
        "atorPrincipal": "Dicaprio",
        "locado": false,
        "valorDiaria": 2.65
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Meu arquivo web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>LocadoraFilmes</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>service.ApplicationJAXRS</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  

</web-app>
```

Meu arquivo `ApplicationJAXRS.java`:

```
@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class ApplicationJAXRS extends Application {    

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<>();

        singletons.add(new JettisonFeature());
        return singletons;
    }       

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(FilmeService.class);
        return classes;
    }               

}
```

O projeto que fiz está usando JPA, por isso há as annotation do JPA além das do JAX-RS:

Arquivo `Filme.java`:

```
@Entity(name = "filme")
@Table(name = "filme")
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Filme implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String titulo;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date ano;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String idioma;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String atorPrincipal;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean locado = false;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Float valorDiaria;


    public Filme() {

    }


    public Filme(Integer id, String titulo, Date ano, String atorPrincipal, Boolean locado, Float valorDiaria) {        
        this.id = id;
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.ano = ano;
        this.atorPrincipal = atorPrincipal;
        this.locado = locado;
        this.valorDiaria = valorDiaria;
    }

//GET and SET

}
```

Arquivo `FilmeService.java`:

```
@Path("/filmes")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8"})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8"})
public class FilmeService {

    private FilmeDAO daoFilme = new FilmeDAO();

    @GET
    public List<Filme> listarFilmes(){

        return daoFilme.findAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Path(value = "{id}")
    public Filme getFilmeByID(@PathParam(value="id")int id){
        return daoFilme.findById(id);
    }
}
```

No dispositivo Android, tal como já mencionei, eu uso o retrofit. Eis o arquivo `FilmeAPI.java` que há lá:

```
public interface FilmeAPI {

    @GET("filmes")
    Call<List<Filme>> getFilmes();


    //Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Filme.class, new FilmeDeserializer()).create();

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();

    public static final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.25.2:8080/locadorafilmes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

}
```

A classe `Filme.java` no android:

```
public class Filme implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer id;
    private String titulo;
    private Date ano;
    private String idioma;
    private String atorPrincipal;
    private Boolean locado = false;
    private Float valorDiaria;

//GET and SET

}
```

E o arquivo `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView lvFilmes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lvFilmes = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_filmes);
        connectWebServiceFilmes();

    }


    private void connectWebServiceFilmes(){

        FilmeAPI filmeAPI = FilmeAPI.retrofit.create(FilmeAPI.class);

        Call<List<Filme>> callFilme = filmeAPI.getFilmes();

        callFilme.enqueue(new Callback<List<Filme>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Filme>> call, Response<List<Filme>> response) {
                Log.i("Teste", "Dentro do onResponse");
                List<Filme> filmes = new ArrayList<Filme>();
                if (response.body()!=null){
                    Log.i("Teste", "Response não esta vazio! " + response.isSuccessful());
                    filmes.addAll(response.body());
                    if (filmes!=null){
                        onUpdateListViewFilmes(getBaseContext(), filmes);
                    }
                    else{
                        Log.e("Teste", "Array de Filmes vazio!");
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Filme>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Teste", "Erro ao baixar dados. Mensagem: " + t.getMessage() +
                        " \n Local Mensagem: " + t.getLocalizedMessage() +
                        " \n TrackTrace: " + t.getStackTrace());
            }
        });


    }

    private void onUpdateListViewFilmes(Context context, List<Filme> filmes){

        FilmeAdapter adapter = new FilmeAdapter(context, filmes);
        lvFilmes.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

}
```

Comment: O problema parece estar na estrutura do seu JSON. O cliente espera um array mas recebe um objeto `filmes`, sendo que é dentro desse objeto que se encontra o array `filme`. Qual server você está usando? Um usuário no SOen disse ter enfrentado um problema quando usando o Jersey 2.x com o Glassfish 3.x:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937826/jersey-rest-server-return-list-as-json)

Comment: Estou usando Wildfly 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bem pessoa, consegui resolver o problema, foi simples:

Primeiro, so para constar e reafirmar, o problema era a forma que o webservice JAX-RS estava gerando o JSON meio paiaçado!

```
{
  "filmes": {
    "filme": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "titulo": "E o vento levou",
        "ano": "1961-01-12T00:00:00-03:00",
        "idioma": "Português",
        "atorPrincipal": "ValdikSoriano",
        "locado": false,
        "valorDiaria": 2.65
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "titulo": "Titanic",
        "ano": "1998-01-12T00:00:00-02:00",
        "idioma": "Português",
        "atorPrincipal": "Dicaprio",
        "locado": false,
        "valorDiaria": 2.65
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Deveria ser assim:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "titulo": "E o vento levou",
    "ano": "1961-01-12",
    "idioma": "Português",
    "ator": "ValdikSoriano",
    "locado": false,
    "valor": 2.65
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "titulo": "Titanic",
    "ano": "1998-01-12",
    "idioma": "Português",
    "ator": "Dicaprio",
    "locado": false,
    "valor": 2.65
  }
]
```

Ou seja, ao invés dele enviar um Array de Objetos ele estava enviando um objeto Filmes que continha outro objeto com os filmes. Ao menso foi isso que deu a entender.
Encontrei uma solução aqui mesmo no stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849526/return-jsonarray-instead-of-jsonobject-jersey-jax-rs

Em resumo:

No meu FilmeService que era assim:

```
@Path("/filmes")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8"})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8"})
public class FilmeService {

    private FilmeDAO daoFilme = new FilmeDAO();

    @GET
    public List<Filme> listarFilmes(){

        return daoFilme.findAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Path(value = "{id}")
    public Filme getFilmeByID(@PathParam(value="id")int id){
        return daoFilme.findById(id);
    }
}
```

Ficou assim:

```
@Path("/filmes")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8"})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8"})
public class FilmeService {

    private FilmeDAO daoFilme = new FilmeDAO();

    @GET
    public String listarFilmes(){

        return daoFilme.findAll().toString();
    }

    @GET
    @Path(value = "{id}")
    public Filme getFilmeByID(@PathParam(value="id")int id){
        return daoFilme.findById(id);
    }
}
```

So mudei a assinatura do método listarFilmes para retornar um String e retornei o List como um string usando o método toString da propria lista.

E o Filme.java fiz duas alterações basicamente.
Acrescentei a annotation @XmlElement em cada um dos atributos dando um apelido para eles com o parametro name da annotation.
Tambem mudei o toString usando o JSONObject passando os parametos como uma matriz usando seu método put e no fim chamando o toString para retornar com o método toString do Filme

```
    @Entity(name = "filme")
        @Table(name = "filme")
        @XmlRootElement
        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        public class Filme implements Serializable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @XmlElement(name = "id")
        private Integer id;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        @XmlElement(name = "titulo")
        private String titulo;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        @XmlElement(name = "ano")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        private Date ano;

        ....

        //GET e SET

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            try {
                JSONObject o = new JSONObject().put("id", id).put("titulo", titulo).put("ano", ano).put("idioma", idioma)
                        .put("ator", atorPrincipal).put("locado", locado).put("valor", valorDiaria);
                return o.toString();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println("Erro no toString do Filme JSON: "+ e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

PS.: Obrigado pessoal ai que respondeu para me ajudar tanto aqui quanto no outro link da outro pergunta!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Acrescente as seguintes classes, tanto no servidor quanto no android:

```
public class ConjuntoFilmes implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private ConjuntoFilmesInterno filmes;

    public ConjuntoFilmes(ConjuntoFilmesInterno filmes) {
        this.filmes = filmes;
    }

    // Getter e setter, se precisar.
}
```

```
public class ConjuntoFilmesInterno implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<Filme> filme;

    public ConjuntoFilmesInterno(List<Filme> filme) {
        this.filme = filme;
    }

    // Getter e setter, se precisar.
}
```

É de se observar que embora essas classes tenham o mesmo código tanto no servidor quanto no android, na verdade são classes diferentes, uma vez que a classe `Filme` que uma referencia é a do servidor e a do outro é a do android. Entretanto, apesar dessa diferença, o código fica igual.

No `FilmeService`, mude esse método:

```
@GET
public List<Filme> listarFilmes(){

    return daoFilme.findAll();
}
```

E deixe-o assim:

```
@GET
public ConjuntoFilmes listarFilmes() {
    List<Filme> filmes = daoFilme.findAll();
    return new ConjuntoFilmes(new ConjuntoFilmesInterno(filmes));
}
```

No `FilmeAPI`, mude isso:

```
@GET("filmes")
Call<List<Filme>> getFilmes();
```

Para isso:

```
@GET("filmes")
Call<ConjuntoFilmes> getFilmes();
```

A razão disso está no seu JSON. Veja os comentários que adicionei:

```js
// Se começa com "{", tem que ser um objeto. Esse é o ConjuntoFilmes.
{

  // O ConjuntoFilmes tem um campo "filmes" que é outro objeto, o ConjuntoFilmesInterno.
  "filmes": {

    // O ConjuntoFilmesInterno tem um campo "filme", que é uma List<Filme>.
    "filme": [...] // Isso é um array de 
  }
}
```

Porém, essa estrutura não está legal, vez que ter ambos o `ConjuntoFilmes` e o `ConjuntoFilmesInterno` é desnecessário. Assim sendo, **se você puder alterar a estrutura do JSON**, recomendo fazer assim:

```
public class ConjuntoFilmes implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<Filme> filmes;

    public ConjuntoFilmes(List<Filme> filmes) {
        this.filmes = filmes;
    }

    // Getter e setter, se precisar.
}
```

```
@GET
public ConjuntoFilmes listarFilmes() {
    ConjuntoFilmes filmes = daoFilme.findAll();
    return new ConjuntoFilmes(filmes);
}
```

Comment: Pois é, o que eu queria fazer era justamente mudar o JSon mas não consigo descobrir como que muda ele, tudo é feito pelo JAX-RS.

Comment: @Hugo Se você simplesmente retornar um `ConjuntoFilmes` e ver o que sai como JSON do outro lado, o que acontece?